# kdiff3 giving error on "git difftool --dir-diff"

Tags: git, kdiff3

I just upgraded kdiff3 on my mac (using brew).  Since I did that, everytime I run `git difftool --dir-diff branch <branch2>` I get a modal dialog box that has the title "Some files could not be processed." and has a text area with zero or more "Mix of links and normal files.".

If I omit the `--dir-diff` it works as expected.

I'm not sure what this means.  There are no symlinks in the directory (at least, `find . -type l` comes up empty).  Maybe I'm doing something dumb, but I don't know what it's trying to complain about.

I can click ok, and move forward, and I get the actual diff, with two hiccups (no idea if the hiccups are related or not).  For each of the files (but not directories)

1. in the "Operation" column I get "Error: Conflicting File Types".
2. in the "A" and "B" columns every square is black.

[This](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1678206.html) looked similar, but is not, I tried the test case and it doesn't even bring up the error for me.

I can't follow [this](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1660335.html), maybe it's the issue I'm having, it certainly has a lot of the same symptoms.  But the only response I see is a request for a test case.

So:

1. Does anyone know what this error even means?
2. Does anyone know how to get rid of it?  The fact that it breaks my concentration is a much bigger problem than clicking the single button.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

There is the answer to this error in KDiff3 Q&A

https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kdiff3/kdiff3/faq.html#idm2019

Git has to create links and kdiff3 has to check if follows them or not. In an early version, this error (when there are links and files) was ignored. Now it is reported.

In Settings/Configure KDiff3/Folder you may switch from "Binary comparison" to "Full Analysis" to get probably desired behavior.